# RHEL6 + Error: xz compression not available

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, xz

When installing packages via `yum` on a RHEL Server 6.6 system, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo yum install foo
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Error: xz compression not available
```

Search engine searches suggest that the `pyliblzma` package is missing.

I can't install this via `sudo yum install pyliblzma` because I run into the same `xz compression not available` error.

Instead, I downloaded the RPM archive and installed it via `rpm`:

```
$ wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS/pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.el6.src.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.el6.src.rpm
```

It appears to not have been installed successfully; the following returns no results:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep pyliblzma
```

What should I do to correctly install `pyliblzma` and fix the `xz compression not available` error?

Comment: Dodgy version of xz installed (i.e. the EPEL version and not the RHEL version) ?

Comment: Have you tried `yum clean all` and then `rpmdb -v --rebuilddb`, then try running `yum install foo`?

And by the way, I see you have installed source rpm, I am not sure if that's any good.

Comment: As @SoumyadipDM mentioned, you installed a source package - src.rpm - which contains the source code and .spec file to build a binary rpm. What you should download instead is http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
Apart from that, `yum clean all` or `rpm --rebuilddb` won't help. Would be interesting to know how you ended up with this issue ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this:

1. `yum remove epel-release`
2. Re-download the `epel-release` RPM
3. Install it
4. `yum install pyliblzma`

Comment: also needed "yum clean all" before "yum install pybliblzma"

Comment: didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me on CentOS 6.X

```
sudo rpm -e epel-release-7-5.noarch

wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

sudo yum clean all

sudo rpmdb -v --rebuilddb

sudo yum -y install libselinux-python
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
yum remove epel-release
# Re-download the epel-release RPM
# Install it
yum install pyliblzma
```